# How to toggle a comment in a line using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a txt file with a line I want to comment, I am using sed

comment out

```
sed -i 's/line1/#line1/' myfile.ini
```

uncomment out

```
sed -i 's/#line1/line1/' myfile.ini
```

this works but the problem is that sometimes I run this twice by mistake, and I end up with a line like

```
##line1
```

so when I run the uncomment command, the line is now

```
#line1
```

is there an alternative to toggle the comment? this is inside a bash script so I am happy to add a few lines if necessary.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```sh
sed -i 's/^[[:blank:]]*line1/#&/' myfile.ini
```

Here matching pattern is `^[[:blank:]]*line1` which means match start of line followed by 0 or more whitespace characters before matching `line1`. And replacement is `#&` to place `#` before matched string.

Similarly for uncommenting use:

```sh
sed -Ei 's/^#([[:blank:]]*line1)/\1/' myfile.ini
```

Which matches `#` at line start followed by 0 or more whitespaces before matching `line1`. It capture part after `#` in capture group #1 and uses back-reference `\1` in replacement to remove just the `#` part.

Comment: Thanks so much @mattb, yes it was a typo and I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Building Upon @Anubhava's Answer,
You can combine the two into a One-Liner to Toggle comments with:

```
sed -Ei 's/^[[:blank:]]*line1/#&/;t;s/^#([[:blank:]]*line1)/\1/' myfile.ini
```

For MacOS/OSX and Other BSD Systems, You can do:

```
sed -Ei'' 's/^[[:blank:]]*line1/#&/;t;s/^#([[:blank:]]*line1)/\1/' myfile.ini
```

This is a simple **"if-else"** statement in sed.
More About Sed Branching & Flow Control [Here](https://getdocs.org/Sed/Branching-and-flow-control)